# Unable to deploy web Application on embedded jetty server on osgi container

Tags: server, jetty

i am getting org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.webInfConfiguration class not found exception.

WebApplication context used for creating the context.

Comment: Need a lot more detail.  Please edit your question and include how you startup Jetty (the bundle list would help, with versions).  And the whole stacktrace that led to that message.